# Preventing overwriting in files

Tags: shell, cygwin

I am trying to run a script on Cygwin that would write

```
alias vi=vim
export USER=esarpka
export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-/home/USER/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}
. $DEVENVHOME/sourceme.sh
```

in `.bashrc` and similarly write this to `.bash_profile`:

```
EDITOR=vim
export EDITOR
. [ -r /home/esarpka/.bashrc ] && . /home/USER/.bashrc
```

But the script is:

```
echo "alias vi=vim" >> .bashrc 
echo export USER=$signumid >> .bashrc
echo 'export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-/home/'$signumid'/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}' >> .bashrc
echo '. $DEVENVHOME/sourceme.sh' >> .bashrc 

echo "EDITOR=vim" >> .bash_profile
echo "export EDITOR" >> .bash_profile
echo ". [ -r $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc" >> .bash_profile
```

But when the script is run again, it just appends the set of lines in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`. I also tried using

```
echo ". [ -r $HOME/.bashrc ] && . $HOME/.bashrc" > .bash_profile
```

for example to insure that the script is just overwritten and not the lines are appended again and again.  But when running echo in this manner only a few lines are written in the files and the files get empty.

Answer (score 0):

The >> operator appends to the file. You should use > on the first echo to create the file.

A solution which would be much easier to maintain and debug, would be to have a master-bashrc stored somewhere and then simply use cp to create the .bashrc, instead of using echo statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look to see if your test is already in the files and only add it if it is not there.  You could make that simpler by leaving marker comment lines in the file:

```
# Begin automatic modification
…lines as above…
# End automatic modification
```

Your writing script can then search for the strings and decide whether to add the material (plus the marker strings):

```
marker="automatic modification"
if grep -q "^# Begin $marker" .bashrc
then
    {
    echo "# Begin $marker ($(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))"
    echo "alias vi=vim"
    echo export USER=$signumid
    echo 'export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-/home/'$signumid'/CPM_WORKAREA/devenv.x}'
    echo '. $DEVENVHOME/sourceme.sh'
    echo "# End $marker"
    } >> .bashrc
fi
```

If you choose not to use the marker, you can look for the lines you add in more or less detail.

Note that modifying someone else's `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` is a sensitive business (though you can do what you like with your own).  Some people — me, for example and in particular — get very upset if someone else insists on modifying their profile or other startup files.  Of course, I keep my key configuration files (such as profiles) under version control so I can recover from such abuse more easily, but you wouldn't be popular doing that to my startup files.

Comment: I do not intend to do that to anyone's file.I am trying to do it for setting up some code.